# Unitary Matrix and complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is an $n\times n$ complex matrix, then $A^\ast$ is unitary if and only if $A^T$ is unitary?

Note $A^\ast=$conjugate transpose of A

I think this is not true, is this statement true or false?

Second question:

Is it possible for a matrix to be both Hermitian and unitary? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first statement should be easy to verify. For the second statement, the identity matrix is a trivial example.

Comment: easy to verify? so the first statement is false?

Comment: It's true. You only need to show that $A^\ast(A^\ast)^\ast=I$ if and only if $A^T(A^T)^\ast=I$.